# Deploy Nuget package to multiple sites usingOctopus Deploy

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy, teamcity-9.0

I have 10 different sites that are the exact same site files just deployed to 10 different IIS sites. The only difference between the 10 sites is a web.config variable SystemID. This ID is used to pull the clients connectionstring from a DB before the user logs in. Once the user logs in, the connectionstring is used to connect to their site. Is there a way to deploy all 10 sites from a single Octo project? I know I can add multiple Nuget deployment steps (one for each site) but how do I set the SystemID in the config file for each Nuget deployment step. I currently have a project for each site and use an Octo variable to change the value in the config file. But I would really like to have a single project that will do this for all 10 sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to achieve

If we define multiple steps in the one project as you suggested

[image: Multiple Steps]

We can then define our values for each site

[image]

And scope the variable to the individual step

[image: Step Scope]

Hope this helps

Comment: worked like a charm the very first time. Thanks for your help.